# Find Computer Name,Operating System name of a given IP address or MAC address In java

Tags: java, ip, mac-address

Is there a way to find :

1. computer name
2. Operating system
3. hardware type(laptop or desktop)

Of a give IP or MAC address in java. I've been give a task to 
get that data. I'd really appreciate a code sample or if you know of any
libraries that can be used. eg :

If I were to use an IP address of a computer on the same network. I would like to know the name of the computer and which OS they are using and other hardware metadata if that's possible.

Comment: How does laptop differ from desktop? Have you tried googling?

Comment: Have a look at `System.getProperties()`.

Comment: Not, only data of your computer. It is an extrange question, you need to conect to that computer to know that info....

Comment: @Assylias he want to obtain that info of other computer only using the ip....

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

I guess you need the following properties:

```
COMPUTERNAME
OS
```

regarding MAC Addrss and IP Address you have 2 options:

use

```
InetAddress ip;
  try {

    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    e.e.printStackTrace();

  }
```

or use ipconfig/ifconfig output but I'll leave the choice it to you

Comment: So your code, Just gives me my systems information. If I where to use an IP address of a computer on the same network. I like to know the name of the computer and which OS they are using

Comment: Don't you think I searched before i asked a question?

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the mac**

The proper way to do this is to use the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) protocol, but that resides at the [Data Link Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) to which Java provides no direct API access.  So you'd have to go native for a good solution.  Use [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/) to gain access to this.

**Getting computer name and OS**

This would require you to tap into some protocol that provides that data.  [NBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP) provides this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find out the hostname associated with an IP address, use [InetAddress#getHostName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29), though that will only work if the local network has hosts registered for reverse DNS. Finding out another host's OS requires either a service you run that tells you or [inference through fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting), which isn't available from Java and isn't entirely reliable.

Comment: Thanks... don't you know of a way to get manufacture name by mac address